# Central place for error/success notification when ising RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I want to make handling notification alerts easy and to be in one place. Let me describe how I do it now. And question is how to do it more elegant

I have a Notification.tsx component responsible for my alerts. It gets *open, type, text* from notification slice. When open becomes true it pops up

**notificationSlice.ts:**

```
const notificationSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'notification',
  initialState: notificationInitialState,
  reducers: {
    openNotification(state, action: PayloadAction<ActionOpenNotification>) {
      let { error, text, type } = action.payload;

      if (error?.response?.status === 422 || error?.status === 422) {
        text = Object.entries(
          // @ts-ignore
          (error.response?.data?.errors as { [key: string]: string }) ||
            (error.response?.data as { [key: string]: string }) ||
            //@ts-ignore
            error.data?.errors
        ).map((message) => {
          return `${message[0]} : ${message[1]}`;
        }, '');
      }
      state.open = true;
      state.type = type;
      state.text = text ? text : notificationText[type];
    },
    closeNotification(state) {
      state.open = false;
    },
  },
});
```

In any component where I use fetching hooks from RTK I do something like:

```
const [createAccount] = useCreateAccountMutation();
const [updateAccount] = useUpdateAccountMutation();

const onSubmit = async (formData: Account) => {
    try {
      if (formData.id) {
        await updateAccount(formData).unwrap();
      } else {
        await createAccount(formData).unwrap();
      }

      afterSuccesfulSubmit();
      dispatch(
        openNotification({
          type: 'success',
          text: 'Account saved succesfully',
        })
      );
    } catch (e) {
      dispatch(
        openNotification({
          error: e as AxiosError,
          type: 'error',
          text: 'Problems when saving account',
        })
      );
    }
  };
```

I feel like I need some way to call openNotification in one place (But text should be customize). I should some subscription of notificationSlice to RTK api.

I have seen the ways some author did it with asyncThunk. He would create errorsSlice with just a string state. And would create extraReducers like `[getAllposts.rejected]: (state, action) => action.error.message.`, and in components he would render state of this slice in errors box. But I don't have asyncThunk and its pending, rejected and  fullfiled properties.

What would be your avices?